# Adding attachment on chatter feed via chatter rest api: How to write contents of binary file in the request

Tags: rest-api, chatter, attachment, images

I am uploading files (attachments) to Chatter for specific items, based on [this][1] rest api reference.

The image files are being created but are not usable, cannot be opened as image files from GUS.

I can't seem to find, how to read image file content and concatenate it into the request, in a way that they can later be downloaded and opened with image editors. I am using Python.

**My current code for embedding the image content in the request:**

```
my_string = ""
with open(filepath, "rb") as img_file:
    my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
    image_as_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
    body_suffix+=image_as_string 
    body_suffix += "\r\n"+'--'+boundary+'--'+"\r\n";
```

**The post request:**

```
result = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=attachment_headers)
```

**Values of post request params:**

**url**: 'https://gus--clicksb.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/chatter/feeds/record/a072g0000048yfwAAA/feed-items'

**Headers**:

```
{'Accept': 'application/json', 
 'Authorization': 'Bearer 00D2g0000000...ZN6tJUKiN', 
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data...0h3VJ7mkI', 
 'X-PrettyPrint': '1'}
```

**data**:

```
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
{
"body": {
"messageSegments": [
{"type": "Text", "text": "Attchment from Jira CFSL project"}], }
"attachment": 
{"attachmentType": "NewFile", "title": "image-2019-07-04-16-56-15-358.png", "description": "attachment migrated from Jira"}
}
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedItemFileUpload";
filename="image-2019-07-04-16-56-15-358.png" Content-Type: image/png 
***add file content here***
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI--
```

Comment: Are you using this sample for reference or have you look at it? [`Python code samples for Salesforce REST API`](https://jereze.com/code/salesforce-rest-api-python/)

Comment: Thanks @Raul, unfortunately this does not help. I am using chatter rest api version 30. the file is being created in GUS chatter feed, but cannot be opened, which implies I am not passing its content correctly. do you know how I can use python to add file binary contents where needed? (**add file contents here**).

Comment: The endpoint you are using is deprecated. You should consider using a current-generation API version and inserting the file and the chatter post separately. Please also bear in mind that GUS is an internal Salesforce system and this is a public forum.